# Scraping data with Python from reCAPTCHA protecred website

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, recaptcha

I've been trying to scrape some info for personal use from a website. It works nice, no errors, but I found out it somehow can't see email addresses from second half of the site. Code I'm using:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://rejestradwokatow.pl/adwokat/abramowicz-joanna-49486')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

kancelaria = [x.strip() for x in soup.find(
    'div', class_='mb_tab_content special_one').find_all('div')[::2][0].text.split('\n') if x != ''][1:]
```

with result:

```py
>>> kancelaria
['Kancelaria Adwokacka', 'Chlebnicka 48/51', '80-830 Gdańsk', '', 'Stacjonarny/Fax: 583054010', 'Email: [email\xa0protected]']
```

Please take notice in last element: `'Email: [email\xa0protected]'`. I believe it has something to do with reCAPTCHA mechanism implemented in the website, but I have no idea how to go around it. Interesting - emails from first half of the site are visible for my program and can be scraped. Anh thoughts?

EDIT:
I'm reffering to the lower part of the page:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to add another answer to this:
That one is created by Javascript, and you may test it using Selenium. The code is provided below.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import chromedriver_autoinstaller

# auto install chromedriver
chromedriver = chromedriver_autoinstaller.install()

# driver define and lunch
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.maximize_window()

# Go to website and get email
url = 'https://rejestradwokatow.pl/adwokat/artymiak-grzegorz-46439'
driver.get(url)
email_text = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="mb_tab_content special_one"]/div[@class="line_list_K"]').text.split('Email: ')
email = email_text[-1]

print(email)
gartymiak@protonmail.com
```

Answer (score 1):

To get just emails, enter the following:

```
email_1st_part = soup.find('div', class_="address_e").get('data-ea')
email_2nd_part = soup.find('div', class_="address_e").get('data-eb')
email = email_1st_part + '@'+ email_2nd_part
```

Full Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://rejestradwokatow.pl/adwokat/abramowicz-joanna-49486')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")


email_1st_part = soup.find('div', class_="address_e").get('data-ea')
email_2nd_part = soup.find('div', class_="address_e").get('data-eb')
email = email_1st_part + '@'+ email_2nd_part
```

Result:

```
print(email)
'abramowicz@pro.onet.pl'
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like it works on page from my example, but I've tried it on a different one, where there's no email in top half and only in lower half but it gave me email address from 3rd part (one hidden under IZBA ADWOKACJA green button on the right) - try it: https://rejestradwokatow.pl/adwokat/artymiak-grzegorz-46439
edit: i see - your solution takes email from top half, not bottom half. I have no problem with this one, but sometimes those 2 emails are different, only that lower part is hidden under `<a href="/cdn-cgi/l/email-protection" class="__cf_email__"...`

Answer (score 1):

The email is generated with CSS. You have to extract attribute values in div `data-ea` and `data-eb` and join with `@`

```
name = soup.find('div', class_="address_e").get('data-ea')
domain = soup.find('div', class_="address_e").get('data-eb')
email = f'{name}@{domain}'
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but you're reffering to the top half of the page. This one is easy and I have it done. I'm struggling with bottom half, below "WYKONYWANIE ZAWODU" - email in this one is hidden for bots.

Comment: That one is generated with Javascript instead of CSS, so you need to setup a headless browser with Selenium in order to execute Javascript and scrape. https://www.scrapingbee.com/blog/selenium-python/